# Prove that sin2α < 2sinα (Gelfand's trigonometry)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The following problem is found on Gelfand's Trigonometry book, page 60 and 61:

https://ibb.co/g0zYK5

https://ibb.co/nQLvXQ

I know that if the diameter BP = 2, then 2sinα = AB

But then how to use the triangle inequality to prove the inequality 2sinα > sin2α is a little more tricky.

Comment: HINT: $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$.

Comment: Yeah man, thank you, but he doesn't introduce this formula until later into the book, Gelfand's question is to use that diagram to prove the inequality and just can't think of how to do so by simply using the triangle inequality. But thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\frac{AP}{sin(\alpha)}=\frac{AC}{sin(2\alpha)}$, i.e. $AP=AC\frac{sin(\alpha)}{sin(2\alpha)}$. Using the triangle inequality, we know that $AP + PC > AC$ . Substituting AP with our formula from above (and considering that $AP=PC$), we get $\frac{2AC sin(\alpha)}{sin(2\alpha)} > AC$. Thus, $2sin(\alpha)>sin(2\alpha)$

Answer (score 0):

$$2\sin\alpha-\sin(2\alpha) = 2\sin(\alpha)\left(1-\cos\alpha\right) = \underbrace{4\sin^2\left(\tfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)}_{\geq 0}\sin(\alpha) $$
hence the LHS is positive for any $\alpha\in\ldots\cup\left(0,\pi\right)\cup\left(2\pi,3\pi\right)\cup\ldots $

Comment: Jack, see the OP's reply to my comment

Comment: All comments, even from higher mathematics point of view, are appreciated. I will revisit these questions someday and something will strike me anyway. Great thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the picture in the link you pasted:

Drop a perpendicular from $A$ to $\overline{PC}$.  Call the point of intersection $Q$.

Then $\sin{2\alpha} = \frac{AQ}{AP}$ and $2\sin{\alpha} = \frac{AC}{AP}$.

Then show that $AQ < AC$. (Hint: they are sides of a right triangle.)

Finally, conclude that $\sin{2\alpha} < 2\sin{\alpha}$.